# What is the best approach to query by various json attributes in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I want to query data from a Postgres database querying by certain conditions within JSON attribute values that are stored in a JSON type column. Those attributes have almost the same name among them and I need the rows which have a value different than "", at least one of those attributes.

The following example is how look likes the JSON

```
{
  "json": {
    "other_object": {
      "object1": {
        "name": "Foo",
        "object1Id": "432"
      },
      "object2": {
        "name": "Foo",
        "object2Id": ""
      },
      "object3": {
        "name": "Foo",
        "object3Id": ""
      },
      "object4": {
        "name": "Foo",
        "object4Id": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example of the data that I want:

the following table has this data, in this example only the first row has value in the object1Id attribute of the json:

```
| table_id | json_column         |
|:---------|--------------------:|
| 1        |{"object1Id": "432"} |
| 2        |{}                   |
```

and I want the next rows:

```
| 1        |{"object1Id": "432"} |
```

I have written the following query but I think that it is an inefficient way

```
select 
*
from table
where 
column->'json'->'other_object'->'object1'->'object1Id' <> '""'
or column->'json'->'other_object'->'object2'->'object2Id' <> '""'
or column->'json'->'other_object'->'object3'->'object3Id' <> '""'
or column->'json'->'other_object'->'object4'->'object4Id' <> '""';
```

what could be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: i'm using 11.11 version

Comment: Is it always those four property names (`object1` to `object4`) or do you want to look at *any* property?

Comment: it could be from object1 to object12 only